# Create sub folders in My Pictures from Windows Store application

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, .net-4.5

I'm trying to create a folder structure within My Pictures folder from a Windows store app. But I can't seem to get pass the first level.

I create my first level folder using the following code:

```
IAsyncOperation<StorageFolder> appFolder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFolderAsync("AppPhotos");

if (appFolder==null)
{
    //Create folder
    appFolder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("AppPhotos");
}
```

Now I want to create another folder below this call Level1.

I was expecting to be able to do the following:

```
appFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Level1");
```

But I don't have a CreateFolderAsync method from my appFolder.

So, how can I create that Folder and then how would I then select it?

Thanks in advance

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, C#4.5, XAML and I'm writing a windows store app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to have missed the async/await revolution there and assume the operation to get a folder is a folder. This should work:

```
var appFolder = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFolderAsync("AppPhotos");

if (appFolder == null)
{
    //Create folder
    appFolder = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("AppPhotos");
}
```

You also need to add the `async` keyword in the method signature wherever the above code is located and then also if your method returns a value of type `T` - change it to return `Task<T>`, so for method signature:

```
private void MyMethod()
```

you would change it to

```
private async Task MyMethod()
```

and if your current signature is

```
private bool MyMethod()
```

you would need to do

```
private async Task<bool> MyMethod()
```

Finally in that last case - you would need to also change your calls from

```
var myValue = MyMethod();
```

to

```
var myValue = await MyMethod();
```

etc. marking all methods that make calls that await other methods with the `async` keyword.

Comment: The `async` equivalent of a `void`-returning method is `async Task`, not `async void`. Other than that, good answer.

Comment: Right, I forgot the rule is to avoid fire&forget async methods.

Comment: But you haven't answered my question. I can already create the folder called AppPhotos but I want to be able to create a folder within that called Level1. That is the question

Comment: If you add awaits to your code so that appFolder is a folder and not an operation - you can just do appFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Level1");

Comment: since people won't let me edit it, could you please change it to `async Task`.
I guess you forgot to edit it 'cause you know that it's bad code.

Answer (score -1):

To create a folder and a subFolder in picture library:

```
  StorageFolder appFolder;
  try
    {
       appFolder = await  Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFolderAsync("AppPhotos");

    }
  catch (Exception ex)
    {

      appFolder = null;

     }
 if (appFolder == null)
   {

   //Create folder
    appFolder = await Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("AppPhotos");

    }

    //Create sub-folder
   await appFolder.CreateFolderAsync("level1");
```

Comment: Gross, just use CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists